# Creating new variable to add up information from other observations conditionally

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This may be a completely novice question, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to go about doing it. So let's say that I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
id<- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5)
type<- c('a','a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b')
percent<- c(.2,.4,.5, .1,.2, .4, .2, .6, .1)

dummy_data<- cbind(id, type, percent)
```

What I want to do is create a new variable, let's call it total_percent, that does the following: If the id is the same and the type is the same, then it adds those up. For example in the dummy data, since both observations with ID 1 are type a, then in the new variable at each observation .6 is returned. In the observations with id 3, two have type a and one has type b. In that the two with type a would add up to .3 at each observation and the one with type b would be .4.

The data should look like this.

```
total_percent<- c(.6, .6, .5, .3, .3, .4, .2, .7, .7)
final_data<- cbind(id, type, percent, total_percent)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

dummy_data %>% group_by(id,type) %>% mutate(Index=cumsum(percent),Result=max(Index))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   id, type [6]
     id type  percent Index Result
  <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 a         0.2   0.2    0.6
2     1 a         0.4   0.6    0.6
3     2 b         0.5   0.5    0.5
4     3 a         0.1   0.1    0.3
5     3 a         0.2   0.3    0.3
6     3 b         0.4   0.4    0.4
7     4 a         0.2   0.2    0.2
8     5 b         0.6   0.6    0.7
9     5 b         0.1   0.7    0.7
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I didn't realize that I could combine the group by and mutate commands like that. You're a life saver!

Comment: @tfr950 Great! Of course you can combine them. Please, if you can, just accept the answer! Thanks!